# Google Maps autocomplete suggestions not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm trying to create an autocomplete for Google Maps in HTML and JavaScript,
and I'm using a Bootstrap modal.
But it doesn't show the suggestions. This is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 Abrir mapa
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
      <div class="container" id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAxBhvzi2eGU7HbBb5cNw5lAkb1eODMG3s"></script>
   <script>
   function init() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     center: {
       lat: 12.9715987,
       lng: 77.59456269999998
     },
     zoom: 12
   });


   var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     searchBox.set('map', null);


     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
       (function(place) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

           position: place.geometry.location
         });
         marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
           if (!this.getMap()) {
             this.unbindAll();
           }
         });
         bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


       }(place));

     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     searchBox.set('map', map);
     map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));

   });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
   </script>
</html>
```

In this case I'm trying to show on modal from Bootstrap. But it doesn't show any suggestions, and it doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's your using a modal you have to change the z-index of the pac-container to display higher than the model and overlay.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
    .pac-container{
        z-index:9999;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>



    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 Abrir mapa
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div>
      <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" style="z-index:9999;">
      </div>
      <div class="container" id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;z-index:9995;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAxBhvzi2eGU7HbBb5cNw5lAkb1eODMG3s"></script>
   <script>
   function init() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     center: {
       lat: 12.9715987,
       lng: 77.59456269999998
     },
     zoom: 12
   });


   var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     searchBox.set('map', null);


     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
       (function(place) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

           position: place.geometry.location
         });
         marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
           if (!this.getMap()) {
             this.unbindAll();
           }
         });
         bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


       }(place));

     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     searchBox.set('map', map);
     map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));

   });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, editing the z-index of .pac-container works, thanks